# Displaying GeoTIFF file in Python

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, matplotlib

I have a list of GeoTIFF files, which I uploaded to [a repo in Github](https://github.com/VicenteYago/cropClassification/tree/main/SO_question/B). The files are generated in R, there I can read them with the `raster` library :

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp 
> r = (raster::raster("./2020-07-24_B.tif"))
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 36, 28, 1008  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 680460, 680740, 4183700, 4184060  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : 2020-07-24_B.tif 
names      : X2020.07.24_B 
values     : 687, 1494  (min, max)

raster::plot(r)
```

[image]

The files load nicely in QGIS:

[image]

But I am unable to make them work in Python:

```
import rasterio as rs
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

```
file = "B/2020-07-24_B.tif"
raster = rs.open(file)
array = raster.read()
pyplot.imshow(array[0])
```

[image]

I followed [this tutorial](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/plotting.html).

At this point I wonder if the file could be corrupted in some way or is just an issue related with the tweaking of `imshow` params.

Comment: My guess is that matplotlib is stretching your image for visualization, but it's also including the nodata value when computing that stretch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. It is just an issue related with the parameters. Without `vmin` and `vmax`, matplotlib uses nodata value as minimum value, and stretches the color map.

[image]

So, you need to specify min and max value:

```
pyplot.imshow(array[0], vmin=687, vmax=array[0].max())
```

[image]

Instead of `pyplot.imshow`, you can use rasterio `show` method.

```
from rasterio.plot import show
show(raster)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Following the comment from @mikewatt, when you imported with rasterio you kept the fill/nodata values (in your case, -3.4e+38) in the raster. This throws off the scale for `imshow` such that you can't see the variation in your data.

Try using masked arrays in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rs
from matplotlib import pyplot

file = "B/2020-07-24_B.tif"
raster = rs.open(file)
array = raster.read()

mask = raster.get_masks(1)
masked = np.ma.array(array[0], mask=np.equal(mask, 0))

pyplot.imshow(masked)
```

You may also be interested in https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the other answers, but adding one trick that can be used: I've found that matplotlib does something sensible if you replace the "NODATA" value in the ndarray with "NaN".

It has these two effects:

- The NaN values are not included in the "auto-extrema" calculation, and you get a reasonable color map.
- It makes the "NaN" pixels transparent in the output.  Work in charts, and -- my actual use case -- when creating PNGs from the data (for display on web slippy maps).